# Inequality induction proof with two variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

For all $ ∈ $ and all $>0$ it holds that $1+≤(1+)^$

I've done the base-case already

[image]

Induction steps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $1+ks\leq(1+k)^{s}$ for $s\in\mathbb{N}$ then we need to prove that $1+k(s+1)\leq(1+k)^{s+1}$.

$(1+k)^{s+1}=(1+k)(1+k)^{s}=(1+k)^{s}+k(1+k)^{s}\geq(1+ks)+k=1+k(s+1)$, where the inequality above holds because of the induction step and because $1+k>1$.

Comment: is that the induction steps? Woudlnt you need to clarify something in the end of the induction steps ?

Comment: The induction step is applied in the inequality. Notice that I could have used two inequalities to reach the conclusion, one because of the induction step and another one because of $1+k>1$. Besides the induction is only on one parameter, namely s, the other parameter k has nothing to do with the induction step but it plays its role in the proof.

Comment: Sorry its because i havent seen the induction steps done like this before. Is that really all that needs to be in the induction steps for it to be proven?

Comment: I have edited my comment. Yes, it is all. I highlight that it is only one step during the usage of the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Ive edited my post to show the induction steps you posted, is it in the right format? Im asking because im really not sure with inequalities.

Comment: This step $(1+k)^{s}+k(1+k)^{s}\geq(1+ks)+k$  which could be done as I said previously in the following way $(1+k)^{s}+k(1+k)^{s}\geq(1+ks)+k(1+k)^s(\text{INDUCTION STEP})\geq 1+ks+k$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120758/discussion-between-gio-and-emil-b).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Induction step:

$$(1+k)^{s+1}=(1+k)(1+k)^{s}\ge(1+k)(1+sk)=[1+k(s+1)]+sk^2$$

But, $s\ge 1$ and $k>0$, so $sk^2>0$.